# Msql-Codeigniter :How to Fetch the data based on Current location/city followed by the other cities from same country and so on

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have search Box where user will enter the Job/skills ,Locations or company name so , my o/p should be from the current city first ,followed by other cities from same country and so on .
here is my query in model

```
 public function searchIn($keyWord,$curAccId,$offset = "0") {
        try{
            $ipaddress=$this->input->ip_address();
                 $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ipaddress}"));
 $city=$details->city;
$countrynamefromip=$details->country;
if($countrynamefromip=="IN"){
$countrynamefromip="INDIA"  ;
}
else{
$countrynamefromip="United States"  ;
}
            $str_array = array();
            $str_array2 = array();
            foreach($keyWord as $k=>$key)
            {
                $str_array[] =  'jp.post_title like "%'.$key .'%" and (l.cityname="%'.$city.'%" or l.countryname="%'.$countrynamefromip.'%")';
                $str_array2[] =  'acnt.accountname like "%'.$key .'%" or (l.cityname="%'.$city.'%" or l.countryname="%'.$countrynamefromip.'%")';
                $str_array3[] =  'jp.extra_skill like "%'.$key .'%"and (l.cityname="%'.$city.'%" or l.countryname="%'.$countrynamefromip.'%")';
                //$str_array4[] =  'l.cityname like "%'.$key .'%"and (l.cityname="'.$city.'" and l.countryname="'.$countrynamefromip.'")';
            }
            $str = array_merge($str_array, $str_array2, $str_array3);
            $str = join(' or ', $str );
            //print $str; exit;
            $this->db->select('jp.post_id, jp.post_title, jp.post_description, jp.ctc_from, jp.ctc_to, jp.extra_skill,
                jp.experience_from, jp.experience_to, jp.createddate, jp.createdtime, jp.currency, jp.rate, skills.skillname,
                l.latitude, l.longitude, l.locationname,l.cityname,l.countryname, acnt.accountname, acnt.accountid as accid, con.first_name, con.last_name')
                ->from('accounts as acnt')
                ->limit(10,$offset)
                //->join('accounts as acnt', 'acnt.accountid = jp.accountid and acnt.accountid != '.$curAccId.'', 'left')
                ->join('job_posts as jp', 'acnt.accountid = jp.accountid and acnt.accountid != '.$curAccId.'', 'left')
                ->join('job_post_locations as jpl', 'jpl.jobpost_id = jp.post_id and jpl.status=1', 'left')
                ->join('locations as l', 'jpl.location_id = l.locationid and l.status = 1', 'left')
                ->join('job_post_skills', 'job_post_skills.post_id = jp.post_id', 'left')
                ->join('contacts AS con','con.contactid = jp.rec_id','left')
                ->join('skills', 'skills.skillid = job_post_skills.skill_id', 'left')
                ->join('relation_requests', 'relation_requests.requestfrom = job_post_skills.skill_id', 'left')
                ->where('jp.accountid !=',$curAccId)
                ->where($str)
                ->or_where_in("l.cityname",$keyWord)
                ->or_where_in("skills.skillname",$keyWord)
                ->group_by('jp.post_id')
                ->order_by('jp.createddate', 'desc');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $list = $query->result();
           // print'<pre>';print_r($list); exit;
           //cho $this->db->last_query(); exit;
            return $list;
        } catch (Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: Please can you provide more detail on what you wish to see returned?

Comment: In my search box user enters eg:java then all the java related job  from the current location should be shown  first in the list followed by other city and country,similarly if user enters company name then  company from current location should be shown